# SQL injection hack attempt

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I have a script that saves irregular strings in the url and look what someone tried to run

```
OPENED: /index.php?function=data:,   METHOD: GET   PORT: 36606   
OPENED: /index.php?classified_path=data:,?         METHOD: GET         PORT: 49650 
OPENED: /index.php?base==data:,         METHOD: GET         PORT: 48062
OPENED: /index.php?G_JGALL[inc_path]=data:,         METHOD: GET         PORT: 33185
OPENED: /index.php?G_JGALL[inc_path]=data:,         METHOD: GET         PORT: 51399
```

What does it mean? I googled G_JGALL and found nothing but this https://github.com/sakti/fuzfuz/blob/master/data/rfi/rfi.txt which i don't understand..
and this http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2007-2158

What kind of an attack is this and should I worry about?

I'm not using any gallery system on my website.

Comment: If you have prepared/escaped your queries and your PHP itself is safe, you have nothing to worry about. These attacks happen all the time and it is just someone who wants to see if your server is vulnerable.

Comment: Might be of interest: http://www.securelist.com/en/advisories/24956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your linked CVE correctly you don't need to care about **if** you don't have installed a software called *jGallery 1.3*. Somebody, proberbly a script kiddie, tried to check for this vulnerability. You may could check for the user agent (if it is not something like a typical browser user agent) and block all requests from that user agent or that IP.

Comment: It's interesting that these 5 inputs were made by different ips

Comment: Maybe a distributed attack. If I would see this pattern on one of my servers I would write a fail2ban block rule to stop that attacks. I guess it is quiet funny to get a 403 message followed by playing death (dropping all incoming packages).